# Textfield is not displaying initial value

Tags: html, css

Ok since I'm not good with css, I am using a free css template and somewhere I messed up, because now the textfields isnt displaying an initial value.

I tested a plain textfield **everywhere** on the page and the value isnt showing however when I created a new html file, linked the css and created a textfield it displays the value.

Can you please point out what's causing this and how i can fix it, or explain how i can override what's causing this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

TEXTAREAs do not use the value attribute. They display what is contained between the opening and closing tags.

E.g.,

```
<textarea name="comment">I really like this article!</textarea>
```

Comment: Not in textarea in a textfield i.e.`<input name="work_tel" type="text" value:"text"  />`

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahh, damnit, why didn't I see that, been going through my code for hours, anyway thank you.

Comment: @grasshopper, the http://validator.w3.org is your friend: it would have immediately told you that there is a syntax error (though it says it in a rather strange language like “an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter” but then adds in fine print: “Have you forgotten the "equal" sign marking the separation between the attribute and its declared value?”).

Comment: I really don't know what to do. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. But it does not answer the question, still it's first result on Google when looking for `textarea`...

Comment: @kap sounds like you need to ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

You Can use jquery selector and val() to init value. 
Just like `$("[name=pageDescribe]").val("here a value");`